# tableView inside containerView does not automatically load on tab switch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I have a view created using storyboards but, But when the page loads, it is blank unless I switch to the second segment and back again to the first segment.

```
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        Container1.isHidden = true
        Container2.isHidden = false

    case 1:
        Container1.isHidden = true
        Container2.isHidden = false
    default:
        break
    }
```

container1 has a list of items loaded from the using an api connection. This items do not show until I switch to the second segment and then back to the first.

I'm new to swift, so obvious things may not be so obvious to me.

**edited (provide more info)**
I created the views using storyboard then connected using the code inside the view class that has the two containers as shown below(superViewController.swift):

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedOutbox: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var Container1: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var Container2: UIView!
```

I also have controller swift files for each of the two containers(`container1TableViewController.swift` and `container2TableViewController.swift`) in which I handle the api request and populate the tables on each of the container view.

```
class container1TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var data = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.handleAPI()
        })
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //some more code goes here
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var returnValue = 0


        if data.count > 0 {
             returnValue = outboxFeed.count
        }else {
             returnValue =  0
        }

        return returnValue

    }

    func handleAPI(){
        //api requests goes here
    }

}
```

container2 swift class file looks more or less the same as the first.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Provide more details on your Container views. is it on the same view controller? what is your entry point for data fetching?

Comment: Can you post more code, please ??

Comment: 1) are you calling `.reloadData()` after getting your items from your "api connection"? and 2) are you calling that on the Main Thread?

Comment: I've provide more info

Comment: @DonMag I do call `.reloadData` in the API. The api connection is called inside each of the swift files handling the container UIViews. Should I call `.reloadData` in the class handling the segmentSelected switch? How should I call `tableView.reloadData()` considering `tableView` is in a different swift file (each of the containers view has a separate swift controller class where the api and `tableView.reload()` is called)?

Comment: ok... 1) Does `viewWillAppear` get called the first time (add a `print()` statement to be sure)? 2) Don't wrap `self.handleAPI()` .. just call it. You use `DispatchQueue.main.async...` when you are doing something from a background thread that needs to run on the main / UI thread. 3) What / where is your "api" function that it is not connected in some way to your tableview? If you are retrieving the table's data from an external source, you ***must*** have a way to say "ok, I got the data, so load it into the table."

Comment: I added the `print("something")` in `viewWillAppear` and it get called although no data loads until I switch the segments back and forth. I got rid of the `DispatchQueue.main.async`(I suspected it was the reason my views take long to load). My api function is defined in the viewsController with the tableView (in each of the container swift files)

Comment: I also put a print in the api function and I affirm that data gets received and added to the `data' object. I'm really confused. I'm been on this since morning.

Comment: *"... viewWillAppear and it get called although no data loads until I switch ..."* -- when you say "no data loads" do you mean your `self.handleAPI()` line is executed, but whatever your code is doing to "get the data" is not running? Or it is running, but doesn't get anything the first time it tries? Or it runs and gets data, but your UI doesn't update?

Comment: I mean It runs and gets data but the UI doesn't update until I click the other segment then the first.

Comment: OK - if it runs and gets the data... after it has gotten the data it needs to tell the table view to `.reloadData()` ... and you said you *do* call `.reloadData()` *and* you call it on the main thread.... Have you stepped through in debug to see what happens when you call the reload?

Comment: I  don't call .reloadData in the entry file that checks the state of the segment(handler class file for the two containers) but I call it inside container1TableView swift file. I don't know how to call .reloadData from a different swift file. I've checked a few ways to do that but xcode doesn't let me declare a custom notification using extension (other answer I read were not swift 4 so I wasn't successful implementing them). I'll try figure the debug thing. I'm still new in swift and that may pose a challenge, nevertheless, I'll jump right in the debugger.

Comment: can you share this code on GitHub, you can remove any business specific logic. Also, are you using apple's view containment API? If that's the case then are you calling didMoveToParent controller method?